# Ayuda conectar a base de datos en PHP 7

Tags: php

Hola Tengo un sistema que en php 5 funciona bien actualice a php 7 y me da problemas con la conexión este es el codigo espero alguno de ustedes me pueda ayudar.

```
    <?php
define('DEBUG', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if (DEBUG)
{ini_set('display_errors', 'On');}
else
{ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');}
ini_set('display_errors',0);
$servidor='localhost';
$usuario='root';
$clave='casa';
$bd='casamanual';
mysql_connect($servidor,$usuario,$clave) or die("Error al conectar con db: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($bd);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
session_start();
?>
```

Comment: En PHP 7 quedo fuera la familia de funciones `mysql_*`, por lo tanto deberás migrar tu código a mysqli o PDO, elige uno y trata algo por favor y te ayudamos

Comment: cual es el codigo correcto completo. favor ayuda para identificar el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambié de `mysql_*` a `mysqli_*`.

El código sería de esta forma:

```
<?php
define('DEBUG', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if (DEBUG)
{ini_set('display_errors', 'On');}
else
{ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');}
ini_set('display_errors',0);
$servidor='localhost';
$usuario='root';
$clave='casa';
$bd='casamanual';
mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$clave) or die("Error al conectar con db: ".mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db($bd);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
session_start();
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Como te han comentado arriba, en PHP7 ya sólo puedes utilizar mysqli o PDO, la cual es una capa de abstracción que te permite acceder a diferentes sistemas de bases de datos utilizando las mismas funciones.

Para establecer una conexión con PHP PDO sería algo así:

```
<?php


try{

$str_conn="mysql:host=".YOUR_HOST.";dbname=".YOUR_DB_NAME.";charset=utf8";

$dbh = new PDO($str_conn, YOUR_DB_USER, YOUR_DB_PASSWORD);

}catch(PDOException $ex){
        echo 'Error al conectar a la BBDD. '.$ex->getMessage();
        die();
}

?>
```

Comprueba a ver si te funciona. Suerte!