# Problema al ingresar datos a una tabla

Tags: php, mysql

Esta es mi linea de codigo para hacer mi conexion a mi localhost.

```html
<?php
//Creando conexion
(linea 4) $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die("Problemas en la conexion");
//seleccionando base
mysql_select_db("gvisitel",$con) or die("Problemas en la selección de la base de datos");
mysql_query ("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
//seleccionando datos de la base de datos 
$datos=mysql_query("select * from usuarioss",$con) or
die("Problema seleccionando datos:".mysql_error());
?>
```

```html
<div class="table100 ver2 m-b-110">
     <div class="table100-head">
      <?php if ($datos) {   ?>
      <table>
       <thead>
        <tr class="row100 head">
         <th class="cell100 column1">Nombre(s)</th>
         <th class="cell100 column2">Apellidos</th>
         <th class="cell100 column3">Telefono</th>
         <th class="cell100 column4">Correo</th>
         <th class="cell100 column5">Acciones</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
      </table>
     </div>

     <div class="table100-body js-pscroll">
      <table>
       <tbody>
        <?php  while ($registro=mysql_fetch_assoc($datos)) {?>
        <tr class="row100 body">
         <td class="cell100 column1"><?php echo $registro['nombre'];?></td>
         <td class="cell100 column2"><?php echo $registro['apellido'];?></td>
         <td class="cell100 column3"><?php echo $registro['telefono'];?></td>
         <td class="cell100 column4"><?php echo $registro['correo'];?></td>
         <!--<td class="cell100 column5"><?php echo $registro[''];?></td>-->
        <?php }?>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <?php   } else{?>
         <p>No hay contactos en la agenda</p>
         <?php } ?>
     </div>
    </div>
```

El error que me arroja es este:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\control_admin\listausuarios.php:4
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\control_admin\listausuarios.php on line 4

Comment: El error se refiere a que estas usando una función `mysql_*` que ha sido declarada obsoleta en PHP 7, por lo tanto deberás migrar tu proyecto a usar mysqli o PDO

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Ayuda conectar a base de datos en PHP 7](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/299184/ayuda-conectar-a-base-de-datos-en-php-7)

Comment: Ok gracias por la observación, me podrías explicar como cambiarlo o que cambiar de ese código, por favor?

Comment: depende amigo, te recomendaría empezar por migrar a alguna de las opciones elegidas, determinar si será procedural u orientado a objetos y una vez que tengas dificultades actualices tu pregunta para ahora si atender algún problema en específico, te recomiendo ver la respuesta de la otra pregunta que marqué como duplicada